Infrastructural diagram with many heterogenous elements
I want to create an infrastructure diagram that has many heterogeneous elements.
E.g. PSTN, satelite, public internet, private network interconnected servers etc. Similar to the composition in the image of the accepted answer here.
What kind of diagram is appropriate? I was looking at C4 but wasn't sure if it is something that I can use for this case or not.

Who is the intended audience and what are you trying to convey?  The kind of diagram you make for network engineers is probably not appropriate for managers.

@JimmyJames: It is a mix of network and application side (services/backend etc) engineers

@JimmyJames's comment is spot on - who the audience is, and what sorts of conversations you want to have with them, drives what sort of artefacts you produce.
In answer to your question, that looks like a "Marketecture" diagram. A Marketecture diagram is basically something that aims to depict key ideas about the architecture whilst not striving to be technically precise, which makes it useful for discussions with non-technical people.
There's no such thing as a formal pattern for Marketecture diagrams, you make up what you need, although you may want to borrow and adapt other existing stuff you already have.
In terms of tooling to make such a diagram, a whiteboard is a great place to start - you want something relatively flexible ... in contrast a UML editor is probably not what you're after.
If you wanted to be technically accurate and precise you'd probably look at some kind of formal UML based diagram, such as a deployment diagram or similar.
There are a number of existing definitions of what marketecture is:

The Hohmann / Fowler view: the business perspective of a systems architecture, including concepts such as licensing, the business model, technical details relevant to the customer (i.e. not necessarily ‘real’ ones). Brand elements, and so on.
The Ian Gorton view: an informal depiction of the systems structure, interactions and relationships, possibly augmented by labels that espouse the philosophy behind the architecture.
The Urban Dictionary view: a fairly cynical view in which the architecture is dreamed up by the marketing department and has little to do with reality.


How would I represent a telephone or a laptop in such a deployment diagram?

You mean in a UML deployment diagram?  I guess you could show that as a Device - as per the link in my answer 'Device nodes are physical computing resources with processing memory and services to execute software, such as typical computers or mobile phones'
